# Client-Server application that can process multiple request depending on the client-side

Tags: java, server, client, client-server

I have a client-side driven GUI (Swing) and I need to process more that one request. I can process one request, For example, 'logging in, the user' but I am unable to make any other request like 'fetch all users' from the server.

How can I process more than one request on the server and how would I set it up on the client-side.

**Client-Side**

```
    private Socket server;

    public ClientConnection() {
        try {
            server = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 12345);
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Connection Error - Client: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void loginUser(User user) {
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
            out.flush();
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(server.getInputStream());

            //How would I write the request type to the server
            
            out.writeObject((User) user);
            out.flush();
            
            User getUserInfo = (User) in.readObject();
            //System.out.println("Response from the server: " + getUserInfo.getRole());
            
            out.close();
            in.close();
            server.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

**Server-side**

```
    private ServerSocket serverListener;
    private Socket client;
    
    public ServerConnection() {
        try {
            serverListener = new ServerSocket(12345, 10);
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Server-Side Error: Connection" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    
    public void server() {      
        try {
            System.out.println("Server is listening");
            client = serverListener.accept();

            //How can I make a request and then process it depending on the type of 
            //request

            //Gets the ObjectOutputStream and the ObjectInputStream and send a User object back to 
            //the client-side
            loginUser(); 

        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.getStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

My initial thinking is to have an Enum class with different request types and then have a switch statement in my `server()` method and depending on the type of request a method is called to perform those actions but I am not sure on how to send a request type to the server and if handling the request type in the `server()` method would be best practices.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to be able to handle multiple behaviors based on what you are receiving?

Comment: Yes @Flav How would I handle that on the client-side and server-side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to think about is how to define the communication between your client and server. Define protocols and message structures.

Let's say you want to introduce multiple request types. It is up to you what those request types will be, but what is going to happen is that you will be introducing the logic to handle the new types of requests on both the client and server.

Just like in REST, both client and server know what GET/POST is - you will also need to have these protocols defined for your communication.

An example would be, your client is sending a request of type `fetch-all-users`. One way to structure this would be:

```
{
   "requestType": "fetch-all-users",
   "body": "..."
}
```

You can have a common module for the enum types, that is up to you.

Further on, we get to the question on how you would like to process the request on the server side.

A straightforward solution would be adding `if-else` logic to process the correct request type based on the provided type.

But to avoid the if else logic, you could play around with design patterns.

Create a factory for your `requestProcessingActions`:

```
class ActionFactory {

   public Action resolve(RequestType requestType) {
     final Action resolvedAction;

     switch(requestType) {
       case fetch-all-users:
          resolvedAction = fetchAllUsers();
          break;
       case log-in-user:
          resolvedAction = logInUser();
          break;         
     }
      
     return resolvedAction;
   }
}
```

And call it in your server:

```
public void server() {      
        try {
            System.out.println("Server is listening");
            client = serverListener.accept();
             
            RequestType type = getRequestTypeFromRequest();
            
            ActionFactory.resolve(type);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It might be wise adding a loop in the `server()` method to handle the next incoming requests

Comment: How would I be able to send a request type and information from the client-side to the server -side. Because I can only read one object through to the server, I don't get the other object. For example, if I need to send a request type and a user object to my server, how/what class, can I use that would help my process both objects on the server side?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer @Bon. Not exactly what I am looking for but I can see where you're going with it. The request type example, you provide is in JSON (if i am not mistaken), how can I work with JSON because I am not using a framework, and I would like it in pure Java (not using a framework). 

If there is an easier way to handle this problem with JSON, how would I do it?

Comment: Yep I understand, one reason why I prefaced my answer with the point that you need to think about defining message structures.
Requests that you receive in the server are just a stream of bytes - how you interpret those bytes is up to you. 
JSON is one way to structure the request, as it is properly defined, and you can use java serialization/deserialization to materialise the byte stream into a proper java class, and vice-versa.

Frameworks are different from a library - java has serialization libraries and you can use them regardless whether you use a framework or not.

Comment: If you really want to avoid JSON - you can make your own byte stream reader, with logic on how to properly read the requests.  For example you can send a request with the string "fetch-all-users;body;", and have a configured reader on the server that knows how to read it. For exampe - ok, request-type is until the first ';' character. 
You are now writing serialization logic, which is good for learning, but of course it would be easier to use JSON and its serialization libraries in java.

Comment: I would like to use JSON if it its better, could you refer me to, where I could learn it or can you show an example of how you would make a request to the server using JSON?

Thanks @Bon

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-serialization-approaches
You can choose what is best for you. There is an example on how to serialize an object into an output stream, which you need for sockets.

Basically, an approach to take would be - model a request structure (define a class) -> create instance of a request -> serialize and send from client to server -> deserialize the stream into a class -> work with it

Comment: As a beginning, you can experiment with one type of request. After that what you need to do is make a generic request structure - where the type is the type of the request, and a generic object property as the body value. This will enable you to send multiple types of requests.